# LinkedIn share button redirects to home page?

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api, share

I have a website that has some articles that I'd like to share on LinkedIn. I'm using the following code to make that happen:

HTML on the article page:

```
<a href="" target="_blank" class="js_linkedin-share">Share on LinkedIn</a>
```

JavaScript that loads on the article page:

```
let shareUrl = window.location.href;

document.querySelector('.js_linkedin-share').setAttribute('href', 'https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url='+shareUrl);
```

When the page loads, it should set the `href` attribute of `js_linkedin-share` to this URL:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://website.com/article-post
```

And it successfully adds the URL of the article page. But when it opens a new tab and loads the LinkedIn share page, the post it's trying to share is the home page of the website. It's as if it only targets the ***'https://website.com'*** and ignores the ***'/aritcle-post'***.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with this code

```
let shareUrl = window.location.href;
document.querySelector('.js_linkedin-share').setAttribute('href', 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url='+shareUrl);
```